# How to transfer all data from one table to another table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to transfer data from one table to another in oracle?
All fields in both tables are identical.

```
insert into second_table (column_1, column_2, column_3) 
values
select column_1, column_2, column_3
from first_table;
commit;
```

The above method will only write the data to the second table, but will not delete the data from the first table.

Is there any function in oracle library that can solve this problem?

Comment: After inserting, you can `delete` the records from the first `first_table` or `truncate` this table.

Comment: Please, describe what do you want to achieve. Maybe `rename` would be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

As you can't do that in just one command, you'll have to use two: `insert` + `delete`.

Note that syntax you posted is invalid; you can't have `values` keyword in this context.

Therefore:

```
insert into second_table (column_1, column_2, column_3) 
select column_1, column_2, column_3
  from first_table;

truncate table first_table;
```

As `truncate` is considered to be a DDL, it implicitly commits so - you don't have to explicitly `commit`.

However, note that `truncate` (or `delete`) *might fail* if there are foreign key constraints which would prevent those rows to be removed from the `first_table`, and there's no `on delete cascade` specified.

Comment: Expand a bit on your response. Hope you don't mind. Wasn't looking to step on your response. Was just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just have a view of the origin table and use the WHERE clause to 'delete' the records you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Littlefoot response you may want to consider using
/*+ APPEND */ for the INSERT to speed things up.

As for the constraints you can disable them if need be. Here is an example that will get you started. When done you should enable them if needed.

```
DECLARE 
 sql_stmt varchar2(255);
 t1 pls_integer;
BEGIN
   t1 := dbms_utility.get_time; 
FOR c IN
    (
      SELECT * 
        FROM user_constraints c
       WHERE -- c.constraint_type = 'P' AND
          c.table_name = 'HOLIDAYS')
  LOOP
    sql_stmt:='ALTER TABLE '||c.table_name||
                      ' DISABLE CONSTRAINT '||c.constraint_name;
   dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;

dbms_output.put_line((dbms_utility.get_time - t1)/100 || ' seconds');

END;
```